# Single color for all background pages in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there an option where we can give a single color to the background of every pages in flutter. I couldn't find one in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

`MaterialApp` has a `theme` property which you can adjust the `ScaffoldBackgroundColor` with:

```dart
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white, //your preferred color
      ),
    );
```